# how to create a comment section for every post from my db selected by user

Tags: oracle, jsp

i need to add a comments section to posts in my website. User can create a post whenever he likes. so how do i create something like a unique db for every post. I am working on JSP/oracle any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table of post where you will associate Post ID with User ID (Assuming you have Posts Table & Users Table). For Comments make a table with Comment ID, Post ID, User ID & Time Stamp !

Comment: have the same table fr user and posts. Anyway thanx. it helped

Comment: And for jsp part: create a <table> and add the rows <tr> dynamically for each loop & comments in <td> !